# How to view and play .mov files on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, video, images

I just uploaded some files to my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using Xender (which is great). The files are pictures and 1 video .MOV extension. When I try to view or play them, I get an error stating

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "/home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV" (Permission denied).
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV'. Check the log for details.
```

Here is the output of `ls -al`:

```
total 497040
drwxr-xr-x  2 blah blah      4096 Dec 21 11:31 .
drwx------ 27 blah blah      4096 Dec 18 14:41 ..
----------  1 blah blah 358905035 Sep  5 13:19 IMG_0002.MOV
----------  1 blah blah  39697387 Sep 25 16:58 IMG_0003.MOV
----------  1 blah blah  72482166 Sep 25 16:59 IMG_0004.MOV
----------  1 blah blah   3468251 Sep 25 17:00 IMG_0005.MOV
----------  1 blah blah  34355357 Sep 25 17:00 IMG_0006.MOV
```

I have searched online, and don't find anything on this type of issue. Any help?

Thanks. I installed VLC and mplayer and changed the permissions as follows:

```
-r--------  1 blah blah 358905035 Sep  5 13:19 IMG_0002.MOV
-r--------  1 blah blah  39697387 Sep 25 16:58 IMG_0003.MOV
-r--------  1 blah blah  72482166 Sep 25 16:59 IMG_0004.MOV
-r--------  1 blah blah   3468251 Sep 25 17:00 IMG_0005.MOV
-r--------  1 blah blah  34355357 Sep 25 17:00 IMG_0006.MOV
```

And both mplayer and VLC play the file now. The fix seems to be a change in permissions.

Comment: Set read permissions to the file
`chmod +r  /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV`
If the file still to playable,
What does `mediainfo /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV` show?
What does `identify /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set read permissions to the file `chmod +r /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV`

If the file still to playable:

What does `mediainfo /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV` show?

What does `identify /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV` show?

Answer (score 1):

mplayer - if you have installed you can use it!..

Comment: Thanks! Easy apt install and then it just works

Answer (score 1):

Change permission properly `chmmod u+r /home/blah/Videos/IMG_0006.MOV`
Do this for all file

Connect to Internet,

Open file with default Video player, it will ask for plugins `gstreamer1.o-libav` and other dependencies install it.

Now Play Again!